# Not able to find some node_modules path when using vscode Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am not able to run node debugger. It is showing following error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'iconv'  
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)  
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)  
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)  
    at Object.<anonymous>  
 (/home/nirmalpatel/codebase/node_test/node_modules/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js:9:13)  
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)  
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)  
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

when I tried to install this module manually, I am getting the error for some other modules. and these things continue.
All these modules are not direct dependencies. These are inner dependencies of the packages which I am using.
When I run the same project directly with the node (without debugging), it is working perfectly.
When I run the same project with the same launch.json(debugging settings) with vscode_insiders it is working perfectly.
I recently updated vscode to 1.24.1. Is there any problem with that?